# High-temperature interactions with salts on nichrome wire

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, metallurgy, pyrolysis, thin-films

I'm working on creating aluminium-doped zinc oxide (AZO) thin films, but instead of the usual glass substrate, I want to try this on a fine nichrome wire.

I'm using a mix of zinc acetate $\ce{Zn(CH3COO)2·xH2O}$ and aluminium nitrate $\ce{Al(NO3)3·xH2O}$ in water. The zinc acetate concentration is $\pu{0.25 M},$ and I'm tweaking the $\ce{Al}/\ce{Zn}$ atomic ratio from $0$ to $10\,\%$. This mix gets nebulized and sprayed onto the nichrome wire, heated up to $\pu{450 °C},$ and then I anneal it at $\pu{600 °C}$ in an $\ce{N2}/\ce{H2}$ atmosphere.

Here's where I need your insight: I'm a bit concerned about how the nichrome wire will hold up under this process. We're talking about spraying salts onto a heated wire. Do you think this could be too harsh and cause corrosion? And how might this affect the AZO coating itself?

Comment: Many questions. $1$) Why are you working with such a diluted solution ($0.25$ M in zinc acetate) ? Zinc acetate saturated solution is about $1.5$ M.  $2$) Why spraying your solution on a wire ? Why not on a plate ? $3$) Why not dipping the wire or the plate into a solution before heating it up ? $4$) Heated in vacuum, zinc acetate is supposed to sublimate. Don't you think this sublimation may destroy your coating? $5$) What will you do or measure with your coating after it has been done?

Comment: Of more concern than corrosion damage might be inclusion of some of the Nichrome metals in the ZnO, an additional dopant. Nichrome is good to ~1000°C or higher, https://asrichards.com/heater-wire/. A Nichrome heater under borosilicate glass or quartz would be my choice.

Comment: @Maurice Good critical questions!

The choice of the process is mainly about minimizing reagents and maintaining control over the film. The classic approach would be to create sol-gel AZO and dip-coat, but this adds reagents. Just mixing the salts into a bath to cover NiChrome results in a uneven and incomplete coat. 

Choice of a wire is downstream engineering, we're most interested in getting AZO electrical properties, low ion bleed and high-ish conductivity.

The true test of this is if we're able to get a solid AZO/salty insulator/AZO interface that behaves like known memristors.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks for this, looking into the effect of co-dopants would be a good idea. And honestly, if I could find a reliable source of fine borosilicate (coated) wire - I'd do it in a heartbeat - Inconel/Nichrome wire is a compromise!

Comment: Oh, isn't that what a fiber optic cable is?

Comment: @ThomasPluck, fiber optic cable is made from *very* pure glass, not necessarily high temperature softening point, and the glass may be solid or hollow core, but most definitely does not surround a wire. There may be a parallel cable for support (and powering repeaters).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Yeah, I was more thinking fused-silica with a simple buffer like this: https://www.edmundoptics.com/f/buffered-fiber-optics/12870/